# knockout js and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I'm trying to load an object with some info I retrieved from an AJAX call. 
The problem is, I can't seem to reload it in the screen, though the code shows no error.

I create my object with a `UserModel`, and then, when the AJAX responds successfully, I call the transform method. I have in the `document.onReady` the call `ko.applyBindings(new UserModel())`.

```
function transform(text){
    var user = JSON.parse(text);
    UserModel.firstName=user.firstName;
    UserModel.lastName=user.lastName;
    UserModel.email = user.email;
    var dateFormat=new Date(user.dob);
    var dateFormatted = dateFormat.getMonth()+1 + "/" + dateFormat.getDay() + "/" +     dateFormat.getFullYear();
    UserModel.dob = dateFormatted;
    UserModel.address1=user.address1;
    UserModel.address2=user.address2;
    UserModel.state=user.state;
    UserModel.city=user.city;
    UserModel.country=user.country;
}

function UserModel(){
    this.firstName=ko.observable("");
    this.lastName=ko.observable("");
    this.email=ko.observable("");
    this.dob=ko.observable("");
    this.address1=ko.observable("");
    this.address2=ko.observable("");
    this.country = ko.observable("");
    this.city=ko.observable("");
    this.state=ko.observable("");
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Common problem that every newbie javascripter face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recommend you to understand java script's prototyping. please have a look at this code.
you have to initiate userModel first properly.

```
function transform(text){
    var user = JSON.parse(text);
    userModel=new UserModel();
    userModel.firstName(user.firstName);
    userModel.lastName(user.lastName);
    userModel.email (user.email);
    var dateFormat=new Date(user.dob);
    var dateFormatted = dateFormat.getMonth()+1 + "/" + dateFormat.getDay() + "/" +     dateFormat.getFullYear();
    userModel.dob( dateFormatted);
    userModel.address1(user.address1);
    userModel.address2(user.address2);
    userModel.state(user.state);
    userModel.city(user.city);
    userModel.country(user.country);
    // now user userModel wherever you want like userModel.firstName()
}

function UserModel(){
    this.firstName=ko.observable("");
    this.lastName=ko.observable("");
    this.email=ko.observable("");
    this.dob=ko.observable("");
    this.address1=ko.observable("");
    this.address2=ko.observable("");
    this.country = ko.observable("");
    this.city=ko.observable("");
    this.state=ko.observable("");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a lot of repeating yourself.  Instead just do this:

```
function UserModel (data) {
    var self = this;
    data = data || {};
    self.firstName = ko.observable(data.firstName);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(data.lastName);
    // and so on
}
```

Then just create a new UserModel with JSON data:

```
var user = new UserModel(JSON.parse(text));
```

No need for a transform function.